# Redux Form Custom Dropdown Menu

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to create a drop down menu selection using redux form, this is my code for the form:

```
<form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.dialogSubmitHandler.bind(this))}
    style={{
        width: '80%'
    }}
>
    <Field
        label="Type"
        name="type"
        component={this.renderSelection}
    >
        <MenuItem value={'price'} primaryText="Price" />
        <MenuItem value={'volume'} primaryText="Volume" />
        <MenuItem value={'dailyHigh'} primaryText="Daily High" />
        <MenuItem value={'dailyLow'} primaryText="Daily Low" />
        <MenuItem value={'sma'} primaryText="SMA" />
        <MenuItem value={'rsi'} primaryText="RSI" />
        <MenuItem value={'macd'} primaryText="MACD" />
    </Field>
</form>
```

And this is my code for renderSelection:

```
renderSelection(props) {
    const {
      meta: { touched, error },
      label,
      onChange
    } = props;

    const errText = touched && error ? error : '';

    return (
      <SelectField
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={errText}
        {...props}
        onChange={(e, index, val) => onChange(val)}
        maxHeight={200}
      >
      </SelectField>
    );
}
```

The problem here is that this throws an error that "props.onChange" is not a function, while in the example here: https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/material-ui/, this is exactly how they did it.

Any idea what's causing the props to not have an onChange function?

Comment: What reactjs , material-ui and redux-form version do you use?

Comment: reactjs - 16.2.0,
material-ui - 0.20.0,
redux-form - 7.2.3

Comment: As we discussed on gitter , `@params mapProps` will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as it turns out, redux form doesn't play well when it is used on stuffs that's not a text input. Therefore, what you'll have to do is to pretend that the drop down menu is a text input. Using that idea, whenever a selection occurs, pass that selection value to the onChange function of the text input. This sets the value of the text input as the selection value. Lastly, set the value of the selection field to the value of the text input. Here's my code to do it:

```
renderSelection(props) {
    const {
      meta: { touched, error },
      label,
      input: { onChange, value }
    } = props;

    const errText = touched && error ? error : '';

    return (
      <SelectField
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={errText}
        {...props}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e, index, val) => {
          onChange(val);
        }}
        maxHeight={200}
      >
      </SelectField>
    );
}
```